# MC API Integration types

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am installing a package in Marketing Cloud and would like to understand the difference between integration types:

Web App

Public App

Server-to-Server

I read the description but don’t fully understand which one to use. Can someone give me some real life examples?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure exactly where the confusion lies, the names and description of the different integration points I feel are spot on.

**Web App** is basically for any middleware system that you set in place. As this is able to be accessed and processed via 'Client-side' (e.g. Web browser), this is not the most secure place to store your id and secret that you use to create the token. So to help combat this inherit risk, they have added a few more steps in to ensure it is you that is authenticating and not someone that is replicating your process.

**Public App** is best described as an actual application (whether on phone, computer, tablet, etc) that is stored locally on a users device. This is very high risk, so it requires the most stringent security methods to be able to authenticate against your SFMC instance.

**Server-to-Server** is exactly as it states, your server directly connecting to SFMC server. If you plan on having an outside CRM or analytics tool access or manipulate data in SFMC, this is likely to be the option you choose.

Comment: Thank you. I need to create Api call on CloudPages triggered by CRM user to modify some data in SFMC - so in that case I should use server to server or web?

Comment: you should be good with Server-to-server